# logic check on a dto and class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dto

I inherited the job of maintaining a small battle game.

The game works, but when the user clicks the "End" button in the browser, the game is never saved to the database.

This method is called after receiving an "HttpPut" request via the API:

```
   protected override TroopMappingSession UpdateGameModel(TroopMappingSession g, TroopMappingSessionDto dto)
    {
        var retval = base.UpdateGameModel(g, dto);
        if (dto.IsActiveBattle != null && dto.IsActiveBattle == false) {
            GameService.SaveToDatabase(g);
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

"dto" represents the TroopMappingSessionDto, which is a data transfer object.

"g" represents the model of the TroopMappingSession class.

"retval" represents the updated model of the TroopMappingSession class.

As it is like this, dto.IsActiveBattle is always "true" and GameService.End() was never called.

If I change ***dto.IsActiveBattle == false*** to ***retval.IsActiveBattle == false***, then it does get called.

My question is, does it make sense to check both the dto.IsActiveBattle and the retval.IsActiveBattle?

I am not sure why the original developer was checking both dto.IsActiveBattle != null and dto.IsActiveBattle == false.

Thanks!

Comment: dto.IsActiveBattle is probably a nullable bool in the database hence the check for null

Comment: @ozzy432836 I just checked, it is a nullable bool.

Comment: You should only need to check for 1 of the three possibilities... Ever.  Just the original coder wanted to be explicit in rejection, rather than implicit via acceptance, if that makes sense.  Also, they may have wanted to be explicit in the handling of the Null value.  Personally, I think have an == in there is really weird, it's already a boolean!!  Why check if a boolean is something, just use it in the if construct as-is.  (If it's nullable, it'll have HasValue and Value properties)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  protected override TroopMappingSession UpdateGameModel(TroopMappingSession g, TroopMappingSessionDto dto)
    {
        var retval = base.UpdateGameModel(g, dto);
        //if (dto.IsActiveBattle != null && dto.IsActiveBattle == false) {
            GameService.SaveToDatabase(g);
        //}
        return retval;
    }
```

Check if the game saves. This proves your retval and GameService are working

Then you can add some logic to ensure it only saves for example if dto.IsActiveBattle is false.

The point being that maybe dto.IsActiveBattle was chaged to true when var retval = base.UpdateGameModel(g, dto); was called.

Comment: Yes, retval.IsActiveBattle was changed to "true" after the call to UpdateGameModel().  However, when stepping through the code, dto.IsActiveBattle is always "true", which is why it wasn't getting saved to the database.